# return specific data from JSON file

Tags: json, ajax

I have a project I’m working on but I know very little about Javascript/Jquery/Ajax and am having trouble figuring out exactly what I need to do and don’t really have anyone around me to ask. Using the JSON info below, I need to include an Ajax call to populate current 'condition.temp’, the returned 'temperature' unit, and set  the weather to be linked to 'link' key in the returned response. I’d like to return it to the console. I have it set up to return all of the JSON data to the console, but am stuck on how to return just the particular data items I need.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "units": {
        "distance": "mi",
        "speed": "mph",
        "pressure": "in",
        "temperature": "F"
      },
      "language": "en-us",
      "description": "Yahoo! Weather for Paducah, KY, US",
      "astronomy": {
        "sunrise": "5:45 am",
        "sunset": "7:57 pm"
      },
      "item": {
        "forecast": [
          {
            "day": "Mon",
            "text": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "date": "16 May 2016",
            "high": 61,
            "low": 47,
            "code": 28
          },
          {
            "day": "Tue",
            "text": "Scattered Showers",
            "date": "17 May 2016",
            "high": 62,
            "low": 51,
            "code": 39
          },
          {
            "day": "Wed",
            "text": "Scattered Showers",
            "date": "18 May 2016",
            "high": 66,
            "low": 50,
            "code": 39
          },
          {
            "day": "Thu",
            "text": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "date": "19 May 2016",
            "high": 71,
            "low": 51,
            "code": 28
          },
          {
            "day": "Fri",
            "text": "Showers",
            "date": "20 May 2016",
            "high": 73,
            "low": 58,
            "code": 11
          },
          {
            "day": "Sat",
            "text": "Scattered Thunderstorms",
            "date": "21 May 2016”,
            "high": 74,
            "low": 61,
            "code": 47
          },
          {
            "day": "Sun",
            "text": "Partly Cloudy",
            "date": "22 May 2016”,
            "high": 76,
            "low": 59,
            "code": 30
          },
          {
            "day": "Mon",
            "text": "Partly Cloudy",
            "date": "23 May 2016”,
            "high": 81,
            "low": 61,
            "code": 30
          },
          {
            "day": "Tue",
            "text": "Thunderstorms",
            "date": "24 May 2016",
            "high": 81,
            "low": 64,
            "code": 4
          },
          {
            "day": "Wed",
            "text": "Rain",
            "date": "25 May 2016",
            "high": 82,
            "low": 67,
            "code": 12
          }
        ],
        "lat": 37.030182,
        "guid": {
          "isPermaLink": false
        },
        "condition": {
          "text": "Cloudy",
          "date": "Mon, 16 May 2016 03:00 PM CDT",
          "temp": 60,
          "code": 26
        },
        "description": "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Cloudy\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Mon - Mostly Cloudy. High: 61Low: 47\n<BR /> Tue - Scattered Showers. High: 62Low: 51\n<BR /> Wed - Scattered Showers. High: 66Low: 50\n<BR /> Thu - Mostly Cloudy. High: 71Low: 51\n<BR /> Fri - Showers. High: 73Low: 58\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-12775789/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>",
        "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-12775789/",
        "pubDate": "Mon, 16 May 2016 03:00 PM CDT",
        "long": -88.712601,
        "title": "Conditions for Paducah, KY, US at 03:00 PM CDT"
      },
      "image": {
        "link": "http://weather.yahoo.com",
        "height": 18,
        "url": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif",
        "width": 142,
        "title": "Yahoo! Weather"
      },
      "ttl": 60,
      "atmosphere": {
        "visibility": 16.1,
        "humidity": 60,
        "pressure": 1007,
        "rising": 0
      },
      "location": {
        "country": "United States",
        "city": "Paducah",
        "region": " KY"
      },
      "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-12775789/",
      "lastBuildDate": "Mon, 16 May 2016 04:35 PM CDT",
      "wind": {
        "direction": 105,
        "chill": 59,
        "speed": 7
      },
      "title": "Yahoo! Weather - Paducah, KY, US"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're asking for.  Typically, an AJAX call will return JSON which you then parse with JavaScript.  Are you simply asking how to get a particular piece of information out of the JSON data here, using Javascript?

Comment: Most libraries for making AJAX calls (e.g. jQuery) will pass the response to a callback as an already parsed JavaScript object, so you should be able to access the subparts of it using "dot"-notation, like `response.data.item.condition.temp`. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes, Tim Morton. I am just trying to just get (parse?) the current 'condition.temp’, and the returned 'temperature' unit info but am not familiar enough yet with Javascript syntax to know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're asking how to extract data from JSON...

If you use the node console, you can dig into it and see the inner workings.

first, assign the json data to a variable, ie

```
var test = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "units": {
        "distance": "mi",
        "speed": "mph",
        "pressure": "in",
        "temperature": "F"
      },
      "language": "en-us", etc....
```

then start digging down the data using console.log:

```
> console.log(test);
{ success: true,
  data: 
  [ { units: [Object],
       language: 'en-us',
       description: 'Yahoo! Weather for Paducah, KY, US',
```

So, how do we access "success"? This worked:

```
> console.log(test['success']);
true
```

But there is a better way:

```
> console.log(test.success);
true
```

Now, how do we get the "data" attributes?

```
> console.log(test.data);
[ { units: { distance: 'mi', speed: 'mph', pressure: 'in', temperature: 'F' },
    language: 'en-us',
    description: 'Yahoo! Weather for Paducah, KY, US',
    astronomy: { sunrise: '5:45 am', sunset: '7:57 pm' },
    item: 
     { forecast: [Object],
       lat: 37.030182,
```

we could try this:

```
> console.log(test.data.units);
undefined
```

Uh, oh... what happened? Short answer, `data` is an array ( `[` )

```
> console.log(test.data[0].units);
{ distance: 'mi', speed: 'mph', pressure: 'in', temperature: 'F' }
```

Let's go one more:

```
> console.log(test.data[0].units.speed);
mph
```

Using this method you can extract any information out of JSON.